# Getting 404 component not found with Chronoforms in 1.5.14

Tags: joomla

I upgraded Joomla to  `1.5.14`. Unfortunately I am getting a 404 error (Component not found) while accessing Chrono Forms component. I had been using Chrono Forms succesfully for a long time.

The stack trace looks like:

```
#   Function    Location
1   JAdministrator->dispatch()  C:\Users\sdelamo\workspace\SVNHenaresAlDia-Trunk\administrator\index.php:67
2   JComponentHelper->renderComponent() C:\Users\sdelamo\workspace\SVNHenaresAlDia-Trunk\administrator\includes\application.php:136
3   JError->raiseError()    C:\Users\sdelamo\workspace\SVNHenaresAlDia-Trunk\libraries\joomla\application\component\helper.php:120
4   JError->raise() C:\Users\sdelamo\workspace\SVNHenaresAlDia-Trunk\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:171
5   JException->__construct()   C:\Users\sdelamo\workspace\SVNHenaresAlDia-Trunk\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:136
```

I really have no idea how to solve this problem .

Comment: what chronoforms version do you use? try to update, if possible. has once solved a similar problem in my case.

Comment: It seems updating Chrono Forms to ChronoForms_V3.1_RC5.5.zip solved the problem

Comment: Write an answer yourself with this information and mark as accepted, so people would know in a answer listing that this problem was solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems updating Chrono Forms to ChronoForms_V3.1_RC5.5.zip solved the problem